# How to get the index as a value, not a tuple from a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series called valueCounts:

```
In: valueCounts
Out[58]: 
StartDate 
1986-01-02      22
1986-01-03      25
1986-01-06      26
1986-01-07      28
1986-01-09      29
              ... 
2022-07-06    1947
2022-07-11    1948
2022-07-14    1949
2022-07-18    1951
2022-07-22    1952
Length: 680, dtype: int64
```

I can get the index as a list of tuples:

```
In: valueCounts.index
Out[59]: 
MultiIndex([('1986-01-02',),
            ('1986-01-03',),
            ('1986-01-06',),
            ('1986-01-07',),
            ('1986-01-09',),
            ('1987-09-01',),
            ('1987-09-10',),
            ('1988-09-13',),
            ('1988-10-26',),
            ('1989-10-26',),
            ...
            ('2022-06-20',),
            ('2022-06-21',),
            ('2022-06-28',),
            ('2022-07-01',),
            ('2022-07-04',),
            ('2022-07-06',),
            ('2022-07-11',),
            ('2022-07-14',),
            ('2022-07-18',),
            ('2022-07-22',)],
           names=['StartDate'], length=680)
```

How can I get that list of tuples as a list of Timestamps or String, or whatever, just not tuples?

Comment: How did you get the `valueCounts` series? If from `value_counts()`, then the index should be just the values of your original series.

Comment: valueCounts = df.value_counts([columnName])
        valueCounts = valueCounts.sort_index().cumsum()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do it:

```py
import pandas as pd

valueCounts = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "StartDate": [
            "2022-01-01",
            "2022-01-02",
            "2022-01-03",
            "2022-01-02",
            "2022-01-03",
            "2022-01-02",
            "2022-01-03",
            "2022-01-01",
            "2022-01-01",
            "2022-01-01",
        ]
    }
).value_counts()

print(valueCounts)
# Output
StartDate 
2022-01-01    4
2022-01-02    3
2022-01-03    3
dtype: int64
```

```py
indices = valueCounts.index.get_level_values(0).to_list()

print(indices)
# Output
['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03']
```